# Formulario dinamico con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia

Estoy haciendo el siguiente formulario dinamico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago click en el boton mas del lado derecho se agregan o quitan filas de inputs segun lo necesite

esto lo hago con el siguiente bloque de codigo

```
    $(document).on('click', '.agregar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var controlForm = $('.controls form:first')
            currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entry:first')
        var newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone());
        newEntry.find('.agregar').html('<i class="material-icons">add</i>')
        newEntry.appendTo(controlForm);
        newEntry.find('input').val('');
        controlForm.find('.entry:not(:last) .agregar')
            .removeClass('agregar').addClass('eliminar')
            .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
            .html('<i class="material-icons">remove</i>');
    }).on('click', '.eliminar', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.entry:first').remove();

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

El campo o input descripcion lo lleno automaticamente con el siguiente ajax

```
    $('.numParte').blur(function () {
        var numPart = $(this).val();
        var inputDescription = $(this).parents('.entry:first').find('.description');
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("getItemDesc", "MakeRequest")",
        type: 'post',
        datatype: 'application/json',
        data: {
            numPart: numPart
        },
        success: function (data) {
            inputDescription.val(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Mi problema es que la funcion del ajax o funcion  $('.numParte').blur solo se manda a llamar con el primer campo y no con los que hago posteriormente

¿Como podria hacer para que funcionara en todos los campos con la clase .numParte?

Saludo!

Comment: Hola `$('.numParte')` usa una clase como selector, de modo que recoge un array de elementos. Debes usar `each()` para recorrerlos explícitamente: `$('.numParte').each( function(){ ( this ).on('blur', function() { ... }); });`

Comment: Lo pude solucionar llamando a la funcion al igual que lo hacia para agregar otra fila de inputs de la siguiente manera $(document).on('blur','.numParte',function(){}).

De igual manera intentare el metodo que mencionas para escoger el mas eficiente

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!! Saludos!

Comment: Es que en el método que usas se recorre implícitamente la lista. Eso tiene como limitante dificultar un poco (oscurecer) las referencias individualizadas en caso de der necesarias. No creo que haya diferencia ostensible de rendimiento pues en ambos casos se recorre la lista; de modo que en principio los dos deben operar prácticamente igual.